# RestyGWT with XSRF

Tags: java, rest, gwt, resty-gwt

I use gwt framework in my project.I decide to rest service instead of rpc and find restygwt for this.Does restyGWT support GWT XSRF mechanism or need other solutions e.g integeration with spring security?